Making disconnectable quartz resonator on STM32: disconnect one or both wires?
I am making STM32 development board and I want to make disconnectable quartz resonator on OSC32 pins that can be used for other purposes, for example, as GPIO pins. I am connecting resonator using Pierce oscillator scheme, see connection diagram in the image:

Image source: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an2867-guidelines-for-oscillator-design-on-stm8afals-and-stm32-mcusmpus-stmicroelectronics.pdf
Can I put only one switch to fully disconnect oscillator from STM32's pin and make it have absolutely no effect on OSC32_IN/OUT pins even if there is any signal on these pins or I need put switch on both wires 1 and 2?

What kind of switch you mean? Does it need to be software selectable analog switch, mechanical switch, solder brige, or jumper resistor? Also, are you more worried about the crystal disturbing the other circuitry or other circuitry disturbing the crystal?

@Justme, switch is jumper, I am worried about crystal disturbing other circuitry and microcontroller.

You can use jumpers to select if the GPIO pins connect to the crystal or some other circuitry.
However, crystal circuits are very sensitive, and the 32768 Hz RTC crystal circuits are even more sensitive.
So instead of disconnecting the crystal from disturbing other circuitry, you should be disconnecting the other circuitry from the crystal.
Many evaluation and developement boards use solder bridges instead of jumpers to select where an IO pin connects. In some cases you need series resistors for the crystal anyway so they can double as a component to connect or disconnect things from MCU.
Jumpers may not be ideal if they allow people to touch the crystal pins. RTC crystal circuits are so sensitive that touching it with finger or oscilloscope may stop it or trigger an overtone oscillation mode, and the added capacitance will pull the oscillation frequency downwards.

When these pins are used as GPIO (or for any other purpose excluding LSE RCC) crystal will not take any function in circuitry so I don't worry about other components influence on crystal, excluding cases when other components can break the crystal.

About solder bridges: I want to make my board easy configurable so I am going to use usual jumper, not solder jumper

@t1m013y I think you should worry. The circuit is extremely sensitive to capacitance changes. Even a PCB copper track on ground plane has capacitance. And two copper tracks near each other have capacitance between them. A toggling GPIO pin will capacitively couple to crystal circuitry through traces and will negatively affect the crystal circuit operation. You literally do not want any extra millimeters of PCB track on crystal signals, so you might not understand how sensitive the circuit really is. Use a jumper then to switch between crystal and other circuit, to keep them separate.

can other components permanently break crystal or they can only affect crystal while power is on and this effect will disappear when power is off?

The question is not that the circuit can affect the crystal, the question is that a crystal with one of the wires (1 or 2) broken can affect the circuit or microcontroller or the circuit can break the crystal in this state.

@t1m013y Which exact STM32 model you are using?

I am using STM32F103VET6

@t1m013y It is unlikely that the crystal damages if pins are used for GPIO. However when MCU pins are configured to connect to the internal oscillator amplifier, the datasheet does not say what are the safe limits for IO pin voltage when the crystal circuit is turned on. But the OSC32 in/out pins have limited usefulness as GPIO anyway, they are special "weak" outputs due their relation with the RTC module. They cannot be used to drive same things than other GPIO pins. They have limited ability to drive any AC loads and cannot be used to source out DC current.

I just don't want to permanently block two pins. So can I break only one wire to fully disconnect the crystal. So can I disconnect only one of its wires or crystal and capacitors will affect other (connected) pin and I need to put a jumper or a switch on both wires?

Another reason why I don't want to make two jumpers is because I am making a small board and I need to save space on the PCB.

@t1m013y Sure you can do it. I am simply saying maybe you should not. Maybe there is a reason as most other boards don't do it the way you want to do it. There is no 100% guarantee your MCU does not damage if software uses the pins as oscillator while hardware allows users to push GPIO signals into them. And I am 100% sure the extra wiring from OSC32 pins to whatever IO header will have a detrimental effect when you actually want to use the RTC crystal, the pins should then carefully be designed for crystal use only, not even going to a pin header. So the crystal might not work due to wiring.

Thanks for your help. Most likely I will make jumpers on both wires that will allow to fully disconnect crystal.

Anyway it is better than directly connect crystal to microcontroller without any possibility to disconnect it and use microcontroller pins for other purpose.
